# org-mode set minimum column width

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I'm currently dealing with an org-mode document stored under git. In this document is a table with wide columns. Occasionally items are added and removed from this table, so the computed width of the columns may change.

In order to avoid massive meaningless diffs, I'd like to set the width of this column to a static value larger than the longest expected string (not just in the view, but in the file on disk). It seems that the method described [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-Width-and-Alignment.html#Column-Width-and-Alignment) does not affect how the file is stored on disk, only the display in the buffer.

Is there any way to set a static column width that controls the layout of the on-disk file?

Comment: Does the `-b` switch to `diff` (ignore white space) help?

Comment: To be clear, I don't think that Org mode can do what you are asking, hence the redirection of effort.